# How to change the start posititon in a edittextfield

Tags: android, android-layout

My login screen locks like this

http://pbrd.co/UVekFg

with that code

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/login_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/login_label_text" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/textfield_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/textfield_height"
        android:background="@drawable/textfeld"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/login_password_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/password" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_password"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/textfield_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/textfield_height"
        android:background="@drawable/textfeld"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
```

Actually the first character starts directly on the left border of the edittextfield. Is there an option so that there a bit padding between the first character and the left border of my textbox?

Thanks

Comment: paddingLeft = 10dp for instance :D

Comment: yes, that's called padding

Answer (score 0):

You should probably provide padding for all the four edges of the widget by declaring `android:padding = 5dp` attribute in your EditText.

From what I see in your screen shot, it would be better to use `android:layout_margin` attribute to provide breathing space between your widgets.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set `android:padding`

But if you plan on using this custom `EditText` throughout your app, you may want to create a `style` and store all the custom pieces in there.

So for example in your `styles.xml`, you'd have:

```
<style name="Custom.EditText.Style" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/textfeld</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">6dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">4dp</item>
</style>
```

Then in your xml layout, all you'd need is:

```
<EditText 
   ...
   style="@style/Custom.EditText.Style"
 />
```